# Get nextjs to produce scss.d.ts files

Tags: typescript, sass, next.js

A project I'm working on needs to output .d.ts files for the scss that is generated. Rather than this being manual, I have it set up in Storybook so that `css-modules-typescript-loader` automatically generates those files.

I'm trying to get the same thing working in nextjs but it appears to not be willing to allow me to do it. I've modified next.config.js to include the following:

```js
webpack: function (config, options) {
    const { dir, defaultLoaders } = options
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.md$/,
      use: 'markdown-loader'
    })
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.module.scss$/,
      include: [dir],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [
        defaultLoaders.babel,
        {
          loader: 'css-modules-typescript-loader',
          options: {  mode: process.env.CI ? 'verify' : 'emit' }
        }
      ]
    })
    
    return config
  },
```

However, if I do that it understandably supersedes the processing that next is already doing (which causes problems), I don't need it to do any of that, all I want is the d.ts files. Is this achievable in nextjs?

Edit: I've tried to use external packages such as `typed-scss-modules` but unfortunately, we use namespaces in our sass files which are configured in next.config.js (see below for example) and that package does not seem to allow me to specify those:

```js
sassOptions: {
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
    indentWidth: 4,
    prependData: `
        @use '@themes/vars' as vars;
        @use '@themes/breakpoints' as bp;
      `
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `css-modules-typescript-loader` before but I used `typed-less-module` in my project to generate typing files. [Typed SCSS Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typed-scss-modules) should work in a similiar way.

```js
// something like this in package.json
"typegen:scss": "tsm ./src --exportType default",
```

Comment: I've tried that already, whilst it's a good solution, unfortunately, it ignores sassOptions which means that I can't get it to recognise the namespaces I've used in the project.